# Google Guava Service tutorial or examples?

Tags: java, guava

Are there any specific examples or tutorials highlighting the use of Google Guava's Service API? For my scenario, the user needs to run multiple tasks side by side or one after the another (one finishes, the next one begins). A task (service) will be started by the user, and stopped at some point in the future and Guava's Service API seems to fit my needs I am looking for a tutorial or example which shows the implementation to get started.

Comment: This post is also a duplicate of this: [Are there tutorials and resources explaining all components of guava-libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237824/are-there-tutorials-and-resources-explaining-all-components-of-guava-libraries)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the closest thing we have is this [page](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ServiceExplained) on the wiki.

Comment: okay so just subclass the `AbstractExecutionThreadService` like `public class UniqueTask extends AbstractExecutionThreadService` and it will run on it's own thread? So I don't need to create `new Thread()` because `start()` will automatically create a thread for me? How would I get it's current status?

Comment: It does start its own thread; you can see it at http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutionThreadService.html#line.122 .  Its status, like the status of any `Service`, can be queried with its `Service.state()` method.

Comment: So do I save the instances of Service in a temporary Map, and later if I want to stop a specific Service by referencing the temporary? Or is there an internal keeping record of all current running Services and how to find and stop a specific Service?

Comment: If you have multiple services that you want to track, then you'll need to do your own tracking -- for which a `Map` would be an okay solution.  Are you expecting services to be running continuously?

Comment: yes, I just save each running instance in a Map with a unique key to reference it.

Comment: I found this link useful to me, and hopefully to others seeking more details on how it can be used.
https://kgilmersden.wordpress.com/2014/03/01/on-the-composition-of-small-java-programs/